# getting off chain data on chain to smart contracts

Tags: smart-contracts, api

Currently 80+% of smart contracts need off chain data, is there a solution to bring off chain data on chain to trigger for smart contracts? (oracles related)

Comment: Could you clarify? For example, an oracle could have special permissions in a smart contract to add data to its storage and then the contract can use that storage. Is that what you are talking about?